# Pl/SQL anonymous block function call

Tags: sql, database, plsql

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = ftest;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
  R_id rooms.room_id%TYPE:='Enter Room id';

BEGIN

  RoomCapacity(R_id);

EXCEPTION
when others then
  dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE||SQLERRM);
 rollback work;

END;
```

Trying to call a function in an anonymous block of sql code. Nothing seems to be making it go into that function though. I have a reference sheet here but it only has examples using multiple functions like this

```
if client_exists(buyer)then
  if car_exists(regin)then
    sell_car(regin, buyer, price, sdate);
```

Comment: Value returned by a function in PL/SQL has to be used, thus you should either use your function as in your example (used in `IF` statement's condition) or assign to any variable.

Answer (score 0):

just use the function directly or store it in a variable like this:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = ftest;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
  R_id rooms.room_id%TYPE:='Enter Room id';
  v_temp <DATATYPE OF THE FUNCTION RETURN>;

BEGIN

  v_temp := RoomCapacity(R_id);
  dbms_output.put_line(v_temp); --displays the result/return of your function

EXCEPTION
when others then
  dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE||SQLERRM);
 rollback work;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hello i have illustrated 2 menthods of calling function. Let me know if this helps.

-- First way to call a function
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = ftest;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  R_id rooms.room_id%TYPE:=&Enter_Room_id;
  lv_var                  <Datatype_of_function>;
BEGIN
  lv_var:=RoomCapacity(R_id);
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE||SQLERRM);
  ROLLBACK;
END;
-- Second way to call a function by direct sql invokation

SELECT RoomCapacity(R_id)
FROM DUAL;
```